# What is the meaning of repeating a site's address?

Tags: url

There is an address like this:

> http://online-forex-calendar.com/sending-sms-alex2edu/Send-an-SMS-http:/www.bnat-ok.com/vbhttp:/www.bnat-ok.com/vbhttp:/www.bnat-ok.com/vbhttp:/www.bnat-ok.com/update-Facebook-with-your-cell-phone.html

Why there is a repeating of second site address and what is the goal of this?

Is it Just because someone has copied the address from second site or what?

Comment: This could just be an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some websites use urls within a url to track incoming or outgoing actions - for example with the php GET functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I dont't really know why they do it, but I do know when it is done sometimes. The forms are a bit different tho.

It could be handy for example on a login page. If you want to redirect someone to the page where they were before they had to login after they have logged in. This way the user doesn't get lost, but usually this is done with a post variable, I see none in the link.

Another example is when you want to know who referred to you. This is most of the times done with advertisement. You want to know on what side someone has clicked your link.

But I have never seen the form of the link you have given. I have no idea why they did that. But having another link inside a link is done frequently, but they use POST variables.